# Strange issue with one CCR node exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, replication

When I fail over to one of our exchange nodes, the store.exe has a very high CPU.  It goes to about 50-60% even with no users connected.  With users connected it stays up near 100%.  On the other node it is fine.  Dont see any messages queuing up, or see any database events and am at a loss as to what to check next.  Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think this one is resolved.  Someone had taken a snapshot of the passive node, once this was removed, CPU levels went back to a normal level.  I will update if issue returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See above comment - was due to snapshot of on passive server